# Byte array to String and back.. issues with -127

Tags: java, scala

In the following:

```
 scala> (new String(Array[Byte](1, 2, 3, -1, -2, -127))).getBytes
 res12: Array[Byte] = Array(1, 2, 3, -1, -2, 63)
```

why is -127 converted to 63? and how do I get it back as -127

[EDIT:] Java version below (to show that its not just a "Scala problem")

```
c:\tmp>type Main.java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        byte [] b = {1, 2, 3, -1, -2, -127};
        byte [] c = new String(b).getBytes();
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
            System.out.println("b:"+b[i]+"; c:"+c[i]);
        }
    }
}
c:\tmp>javac Main.java
c:\tmp>java Main
b:1; c:1
b:2; c:2
b:3; c:3
b:-1; c:-1
b:-2; c:-2
b:-127; c:63
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The constructor you're calling makes it non-obvious that binary-to-string conversions use a decoding: `String(byte[] bytes, Charset charset)`.  What you want is to use no decoding at all.

Fortunately, there's a constructor for that: `String(char[] value)`.

Now you have the data in a string, but you want it back exactly as is.  But guess what!  `getBytes(Charset charset)`  That's right, there's an encoding applied automatically also.  Fortunately, there is a    `toCharArray()` method.

If you must start with bytes and end with bytes, you then have to map the char arrays to bytes:

```
(new String(Array[Byte](1,2,3,-1,-2,-127).map(_.toChar))).toCharArray.map(_.toByte)
```

So, to summarize: converting between `String` and `Array[Byte]` involves encoding and decoding.  If you want to put binary data in a string, you have to do it at the level of characters.  Note, however, that this will give you a garbage string (i.e. the result will not be well-formed UTF-16, as `String` is expected to be), and so you'd better read it out as characters and convert it back to bytes.

You *could* shift the bytes up by, say, adding 512; then you'd get a bunch of valid single `Char` code points.  But this is using 16 bits to represent every 8, a 50% encoding efficiency.  Base64 is a better option for serializing binary data (8 bits to represent 6, 75% efficient).

Answer (score 12):

String is for storing text not binary data.

In your default character encoding there is no charcter for -127 so it replaces it with '?' or 63.

EDIT: Base64 is the best option, even better would be to not use text to store binary data.  It can be done, but not with any standard character encoding. i.e. you have to do the encoding yourself.

To answer your question literally, you can use your own character encoding. This is a very bad idea as any text is likely to get encoded and mangled in the same way as you have seen.  Using Base64 avoids this by using characters which are safe in any encoding.

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[256];
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++)
    bytes[i] = (byte) i;
String text = new String(bytes, 0);
byte[] bytes2 = new byte[text.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < bytes2.length; i++)
    bytes2[i] = (byte) text.charAt(i);
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < bytes2.length; i++)
    if (bytes2[i] != (byte) i)
        System.out.println(i);
    else
        count++;
System.out.println(count + " bytes matched.");
```

Comment: so I guess converting to base64 is my only option.

Answer (score 9):

StringOps has a method `getBytes`, I think that is probably what one actually wants for converting String to Array[Byte]

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.2/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.StringOps

Comment: Can you explain how this is different from Java's `getBytes`, and why this works? There does not seem to be any explanation at the link.

Answer (score 5):

Use correct charset:

```
scala> (new String(Array[Byte](1, 2, 3, -1, -2, -127), "utf-16")).getBytes("utf-16")
res13: Array[Byte] = Array(-2, -1, 1, 2, 3, -1, -2, -127)
```