# Sending avro to spark streaming through kafka

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I am getting output in form of byte array, is there any function to convert it to string?

```
stream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
   rdd.foreach(record => parseAVROToString(record))
})
stream.print
ssc.start()

message-
{
    "id":"1",
    "url":"http://localhost.com",
    "article":" xyz",
    "timestamp": 1366150681
}
```

Receiving:
[B@1ffc17a0

I want to convert it to string.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250324/byte-array-to-string-and-back-issues-with-127). Watch out the encoding.

Comment: using a map instead of a foreach can help? val res = stream.map{record => parseAVROToString(record)} and then printing res

Comment: doesn't work this way!

Answer (score 0):

```
stream.foreachRDD((rdd, time) => {
              val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
              import sqlContext.implicits._

              val jsonString = rdd.map { case (k, v) =>   AvroUtil.parseAVROToString(v) }
              try {
                val result = jsonString.mapPartitions(records => {
                  val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
                  mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
                  mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
                  records.flatMap(record => {
                    try {
                      Some(mapper.readValue(record, classOf[Article]))
                    } catch {
                      case e: Exception => None
                    }
                  })
                }, true)

                val df1 = result.toDF()
                df1.show()
                df1.write.format("json").mode(org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode.Append).json("jsonresults")
                //df1.save("org.apache.phoenix.spark", org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode.Overwrite, Map("table" -> "articles".toUpperCase,"zkUrl" -> zkQuorum+":\hbase-unsecure"))
              } catch {
                case e: Exception => None;
              }
            }
```